# Multi-Tenant and Central Database with Spring Boot and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

## Specification

Each tenant has their own database which handles users in greater detail, and there needs to exist a central database which handles:

- Tokens (OAuth2)
- Users (limited level of detail)
- Mapping users to their database

## Problem

I've found [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472097/variable-datasource-based-on-user) for multi-tenancy which allows me to determine the datasource depending on the user. However, I'm not sure how I can also link certain crud repositories to this central datasource, and others to variable datasources.

Another [solution](http://jeroenbellen.com/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/) involved updating the properties file, and using a configuration server (i.e. via git) to trigger @RefreshScope annotated configs. Though I'm not sure if this can work for Datasources, or if this could cause problems later on.

### Extra Context

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate heavily in this project.

Comment: Take a look to this blog https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: @WilderValera I already came across the blog, and it got my hopes up for sure. Thing is, this relies on configuration via the properties file which is what I'm trying to avoid (unless Spring-Actuator refresh can allow me to add any number of databases?)

Comment: If your config comes from a central DB remember that you can register Bean programmatically(TransactionManagement, Datasources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog](https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2018/05/adding-tenants-without-application.html?_sm_au_=iVV27sL7KkDR1PWr) gives a very good tutorial on how to do it.

After a lot of research it looks like hibernate just isn't built for doing that, but by manually writing the schema myself I can inject that into new tenant databases using native queries.

I also had a problem with MS Server DBs, as they don't allow simply appending `;createDatabaseIfNotExist` to the JDBC URL, which meant even more native queries (Moving the project over to use MySQL anyway, so this is no longer a problem.)